# Put weeknum in an array?

Tags: excel, vba, date

Here is what im trying to do: **Cell B2: Start Date** and **Cell B3: End Date**

Example: 
 
B2 --> 01/01/2019 
B3 --> 01/03/2019

I would like to get all the week numbers and put them in an array

Here is a picture of the Excel cells

[image]

Here is my code so far

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim StartD As Date, EndD As Date 
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Foglio1")

Worksheets("Foglio1").Range("D2:XZ39").Clear 

StartD = Worksheets("Foglio1").Cells(2, 2) 
EndD = Worksheets("Foglio1").Cells(3, 2)
```

I would like to loop though the given two dates: **01/01/2019** , **01/03/2019** get the week numbers and put them in an array(if it's possible)

So my output would be:

Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) --> Since between January and March there are 9 weeks

Comment: Just curious... how did you get 9 weeks :) Try this `Datediff("ww",dateserial(2019,1,1),dateserial(2019,3,1))`

Comment: In my Calendar February days are: **25, 26, 27, 28** in the 9 week and 
March: **1, 2, 3** still week 9, Am I doing someting wrong?

Comment: It depends on what you think is a week :) There are 8 **Calendar Weeks** between those dates. See [this](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2019)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Yes sorry, I was actually looking at my Calendar Weeks... [link](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=zE5yXdzOEuO78gKA1Zpw&q=2019+calendar+week&oq=2019+calendar+&gs_l=img.1.0.0l4j0i30l6.21427.21427..23304...0.0..0.241.241.2-1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.ed8JthTXTs0#imgrc=Y30-D9mQl6ESQM:)

Comment: If you do not want **Calendar Weeks** and want to include a week even if there is one day from it , then you can use `DateAdd()` to get the count of 9 by automatically incrementing the initial date.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Can you show an example of how to do that using DateAdd()?

Comment: While experimenting I found a better way than `DateAdd()`. I was in fact posting an answer (almost half way through it) @YasserKhalil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want **Calendar Weeks** and want to include a week even if there is one day from it then you can try this.

Logic

1. It finds when the next week is starting. So default number of weeks is `1`.
2. Loops and counts the number of days (Say *Monday* and then *Tuesday* and so on) between two dates and whichever is highest, it returns it and adds it to `1`.

Also there is no need to loop and create an array. You can create a sequential array in **One Go**

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim WeeksCount As Long
    Dim CurCount As Long
    Dim countOfWeeks As Long
    Dim i As Long, tmpCount As Long

    Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date

    sDate = DateSerial(2019, 1, 6)
    eDate = DateSerial(2019, 1, 8)

    If Weekday(sDate, vbMonday) <> 1 Then
        sDate = DateAdd("d", 7 - Weekday(sDate, vbMonday) + 1, sDate)
        WeeksCount = 1
    End If

    For i = 1 To 7
        CurCount = GetMeMyKindOfWeeksTotal(sDate, eDate, i)
        If tmpCount < CurCount Then tmpCount = CurCount
    Next i

    WeeksCount = WeeksCount + tmpCount

    Dim MyArray

    MyArray = Evaluate("Row(1" & ":" & WeeksCount & ")")

    If WeeksCount = 1 Then
        Debug.Print MyArray(1)
    Else
        For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
            Debug.Print MyArray(i, 1)
        Next i
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetMeMyKindOfWeeksTotal(ByVal sDate As Date, ByVal eDate As Date, dy As Long)
    Dim j As Long
    Dim TotalDays As Long

    For j = sDate To eDate
        If Weekday(j) = dy Then
            TotalDays = TotalDays + 1
        End If
    Next

    GetMeMyKindOfWeeksTotal = TotalDays
End Function
```

**Various Tests**

```
sDate = DateSerial(2019, 1, 6)
eDate = DateSerial(2019, 1, 8)
```

This will give you `2`

```
sDate = DateSerial(2019, 1, 1)
eDate = DateSerial(2019, 3, 1)
```

This will give you `9`

```
sDate = DateSerial(2019, 1, 1)
eDate = DateSerial(2019, 1, 1)
```

This will give you `1`

```
sDate = DateSerial(2019, 1, 1)
eDate = DateSerial(2019, 1, 8)
```

This will give you `2`

Comment: I got stuck working with your code, because it actually gives me the number of weeks between the two given dates, but I didn't realise that it always counts from 1 to the proper end. But if I write `Start Date: 01/02/2019` and `End Date: 01/03/2019` it always give me `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. BUT you said it in the answer 
`If you do not want Calendar Weeks...` so it's my fault, do I need to open another question or you can help me to update yours?

Comment: The actual result from `Start Date: 01/02/2019` and `End Date: 01/03/2019` would be `5, 6, 7, 8, 9` still confused...

Comment: It should be a different question becuase if you look at [THIS](https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2019), it should be `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9` and not `5, 6, 7, 8, 9` For what you want, a new question has to be asked where you have to explain how did you get `5, 6, 7, 8, 9` :)

Comment: do post a link here after you ask the quesiton

Comment: ok Siddharth thank you, I will ask a new question. Your the best btw

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date
    Dim NoOfWeeks As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Foglio1")
        sDate = .Range("B2")

        If Weekday(sDate, vbMonday) <> 1 Then
            sDate = DateAdd("d", 7 - Weekday(sDate, vbMonday) + 1, sDate)
            NoOfWeeks = 1
        End If

        eDate = .Range("B3")
    End With

    If sDate = eDate Then
        NoOfWeeks = NoOfWeeks + 1
    Else
        NoOfWeeks = NoOfWeeks + WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((eDate - sDate) / 7, 0)
    End If

    ReDim arr(1 To NoOfWeeks)
    For i = 1 To NoOfWeeks
        arr(i) = i
    Next i

    MsgBox Join(arr, ";")
End Sub
```

Comment: While trying the code, seems like last week is missing.
My current output is: **1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8** week 9 is missing.

Comment: @ChangeWorld If you want to include the last week use `NoOfWeeks = 
 worksheetfunction.ROUNDUP((EndDate.Value2 - StartDate.Value2) / 7,0)` It rounds down by default as it isn't a full week between the two dates (comes to 8.5ish)

Comment: It gives me a Compilation error: **argument not optional** with **.ROUNDUP** underlined

Comment: Sorry forgot the `0` - `NoOfWeeks = 
 worksheetfunction.ROUNDUP((EndDate.Value2 - StartDate.Value2) / 7,0)`

Comment: I have a question for you @ChangeWorld. If start date is `1st Jan 2019` and end date is `8th Jan 2019` then how many weeks should the code return as per you?

Comment: @SiddharthRout 2 weeks, because `8th Jan 2019` is part of the 2nd week of January, but I'm working on a Planning Excel, so it doesn't matter if the week has 1,2 or 7 days. For me is a week. (Maybe I've should specify that at the start of the question, sorry I'm improving)

Comment: @ChangeWorld: I asked you that question so that I could improve my answer... No disrespect to Tom here but his code will not give you 2 weeks for the above days... Nor will mine. Give me some time and it will update my answer

Comment: @SiddharthRout That's true! But when I tried it for **01/01/2019** and **01/03/2019** Toms code worked! How's that possible that is not working for **01/01/2019** and **08/01/2019**?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Non-taken - you're right it won't but it depends what @ ChangeWorld is really looking for

Comment: @ChangeWorld: you did not have to unselect this answer. I was just trying to give a more detailed answer. You can keep this answer selected. With a slight modification, Tom's answer will also work in your case...

Comment: @SiddharthRout I acknowledge your hard work, if It's not a problem for you, I preferer your answer to be selected, because Its explained very good and It's very accurate.

Comment: @Tom: With your permission, may I edit your answer?

Comment: @SiddharthRout go for it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a UDF like below:

```
Public Function GetWeekNums(startDate As Date, endDate As Date, Optional varDelim As Variant)
Dim lngStartWeek As Long
Dim lngEndWeek As Long
Dim i As Long

If IsMissing(varDelim) Then varDelim = ","

lngStartWeek = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(startDate)
lngEndWeek = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(endDate)
For i = lngStartWeek To lngEndWeek
    GetWeekNums = GetWeekNums & " " & i
Next

GetWeekNums = Replace(Trim(GetWeekNums), " ", varDelim & " ")

End Function
```

and then use it in workbook like:

`=GetWeekNums(B2,B3,";")`

Answer (score 0):

If someone prefers just a worksheet formula, you can use:

```
=ROW(INDEX($A:$A,WEEKNUM($B$2),1):INDEX($A:$A,WEEKNUM($B$3),1))
```

Depending on when your week starts, use the appropriate `return_type` argument for the function.